# Does twitter4j.Status return geo location on every tweet

Tags: twitter, geolocation, twitter4j

http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html return a GeoLocation object containing latitude / longitude (http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/GeoLocation.html). Does it return the values for all tweets, since I am observing that the object is null most of the times. When does it return a geo location for a tweet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geographic coordinates are only provided when the tweet itself has been explicitly geotagged by the user. The Search API does some fuzzy matching based on the user-provided location field, which is why you'll get results that do not have coordinates included. v1 Search results do not contain complete tweet or user objects.

[Source](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10821) and try googling "geolocation in tweets null", there are plenty of discussions on the dev.twitter forums.